# Shift + double click opens Chrome DevTools on MacOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-shortcuts

This has been bothering me for a long time. I have no idea why this would happen. This is not the default shortcut and I never changed shortcuts for Chrome.

I can't find any shortcuts setting to forbidden that. And I can't find anyone else having the same problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This have been bothered me for a long time too. I just figured out that It's caused by some other App. In my case, the EuDic App. Once I turn off "开启划词搜索", problem solved. You may quit the running apps one by one to find out the culprit.

[image]

Comment: I have the same software!!!!! You are a genius!!!!!!!!!